# Personal Streaming Website

Tags: windows, streaming, web-server

I am looking for a **service** that will allow me to stream live media generated by OBS (Open Broadcaster Studio) or VLC. The intention is to use my laptop to record my house whilst I am at the office, and allow me to view the content. For security reasons, I don't want to stream to YouTube.

The end-client (as in, me viewing the video) **must** be Windows 10 supported, and I'd prefer free or Open Source solutions.

Comment: Ryan, would it be appropriate to simply `RDP` into your laptop from home, and simply have the client open (OBS) saving the data locally for viewing purposes later?